# Why do i get the following error while running a java web application?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I am following this tutorial 
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html

and as mentioned i have created two jsp pages.My index.jsp page looks like this

```
%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        Name<form name="Name Input Form" action="response.jsp">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="OK" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

and my response.jsp looks like this

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <jsp:useBean id="useBean" scope="session" class="abc.NameHandler" />

        <jsp:setProperty name="myBean" property="name" /><h1>Hello</h1>
        <jsp:getProperty name="myBean" property="name" />

    </body>
</html>
```

and i have created a package named abc where i ave defined a class named NameHandler.

```
package abc;

public class NameHandler 
{

    private String name;

    public NameHandler() 
    {
        name =null;

    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

when i run the project index.jsp is displayed correctly and it commands to enter a name and it has a submit button.Now when i press the submit button i get the following error.

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1
```

ANd i have no idea why i get this error.Could anyone please explain?

**[UPDATE]**

What does this error means?

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.internalIntrospecthelper(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:368)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspecthelper(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:354)
    at org.apache.jsp.response_jsp._jspService(response_jsp.java from :68)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: As suggested in the error message take a look at the full stack trace: it will tell you where the error is occurring.

Comment: i dont unserstand what the error log says                                                                        WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in / marked with the position attribute: [org-netbeans-modules-editor-java-JavaBracesMatcher.shadow], but some are: [org-netbeans-modules-editor-bracesmatching-LegacyEssMatcher.instance, org-netbeans-modules-editor-bracesmatching-DefaultMatcher.instance]
INFO [org.netbeans.lib.profiler.infolog]: >>> Profiler agent [port=5140, id=-1]: STATE_INACTIVE

Comment: "The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1". If, as it seems, you are using glassfish, check the server.log file in your glassfish installation.

Comment: Don't post the stack trace in a comment: edit your question and add it there (otherwise it will be difficult to read).

Comment: OT: Frankly, this tutorial is crap. jsp:useBean, jsp:getProperty etc. shouldn't be used anymore, and for a long long time. Learn an MVC framework, and use the JSTL and the JSP EL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id and name of bean in `jsp:useBean` and `jsp:setProperty` / `jsp:getProperty` should match:

```
   <jsp:useBean id="myBean" scope="session" class="abc.NameHandler" />

   <jsp:setProperty name="myBean" property="name" /><h1>Hello</h1>
   <jsp:getProperty name="myBean" property="name" />
```